# how to send different views as different attachments in android

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, android-sdcard

I want to share different views in my screens which are not visible in PNG format via email.

I have tried below code to save my view into SD Card. But I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
private void loadBitmapSaveSdcard() {
    View content = view;
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
    File file = new File("/sdcard/" + "yourimagename" + ".png");
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
        ostream.close();
        content.invalidate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Logcat,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$Com‌​pressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
    at com.novartis.tjrup.sendinfo.SendInfoFragment.loadBitmapSaveS‌​dcard(SendInfoFragme‌​nt.java:170)
    at com.novartis.tjrup.sendinfo.SendInfoFragment.onCreateView(Se‌​ndInfoFragment.java:‌​57)
```

Anyone please help on this.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
    at com.novartis.tjrup.sendinfo.SendInfoFragment.loadBitmapSaveSdcard(SendInfoFragment.java:170)
    at com.novartis.tjrup.sendinfo.SendInfoFragment.onCreateView(SendInfoFragment.java:57)

Comment: Is the View visible?

Comment: No ,View is not visisble